How do I make a dropdown list open as soon as an option from another drop-down list is selected?
In this product upload form, I have five drop-down list fields created using HTML (2 selects and 3 data lists with text area), and I have embedded Javascript to dynamically populate the options in the drop-down lists. My question is how do I get the second drop-down list to open as soon as an option is selected in the first drop-down list? Then, once an option in the second drop-down list is selected, how do I get the third drop-down list to then open automatically? and so on for each drop-down list after that. Here is the sample code (apologies if it's unnecessarily long, I've tried to remove as much as possible whilst still leaving context):


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Upload Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Product Upload Form</h2>
    <form id="upload-form" form action="Upload_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="type">Product Type:</label>
        <select id="type" name="type">
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="Shotgun">Shotgun</option>
            <option value="Rifle">Rifle</option>
            <option value="Air Rifle">Air Rifle</option>
            <option value="Air Pistol">Air Pistol</option>
        </select>

        <label for="action">Action:</label>
        <select id="action" name="action">
            <!-- Subcategory options will be dynamically added here -->
        </select>


    <div class="field-container">
        <label for="make">Make:</label>
        <input type="text" id="makeInput" name="make" list="makeList">
        <datalist id="makeList">
    <!-- Add options dynamically using JavaScript -->
        </datalist>



        <label for="model">Model:</label>
        <input type="text" id="modelInput" name="model" list="modelList">
        <datalist id="modelList">
        </datalist>


        <label for="variant">Variant:</label>
        <input type="text" id="variantInput" name="variant" list="variantList">
        <datalist id="variantList">
        <!-- Add options dynamically using JavaScript -->
        </datalist>


        <label id="stockLabel" for="stock">Stock Material:</label>
        <input type="text" id="stockInput" name="stock" list="stockList">
        <datalist id="stockList">
        </datalist>
    </div>
</form>
<script>

// Populate Action & Make options based on selected Product Type
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", function () {
        var type = this.value;
        var actionDropdown = document.getElementById("action");
        var makeDropdown = document.getElementById("makeList");
        var stockDropdown = document.getElementById("stockList");
        actionDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Action when Type changes
        makeDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Make when Type changes
        stockDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Stock when Type changes

// Populate 'Action' and 'Make' options for Rifles
        if (type === "Rifle") {
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Bolt Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Straight Pull");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Semi Automatic");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Single Shot");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pump Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Lever Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Over & Under");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Side-by-side");
        

             // Populate 'Make' options for Rifles
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Accuracy International");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Anschutz");
}

else if (type === "Shotgun") {
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Over & Under");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Side-by-side");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Semi Automatic");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Single Shot");

// Populate Make options for Shotguns
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Abbiatico & Salvinelli");
}

else if (type === "Air Rifle") {
            // Populate Action options for Air Rifles
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel - Spring");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel -Gas Ram");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pre-Charged Pneumatic (PCP)");

// Populate 'Make' options for Air Rifles
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Air Arms");
}

// Populate Action options for Air Pistols
        else if (type === "Air Pistol") {
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel - Spring");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel - Gas Ram");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pre-Charged Pneumatic (PCP)");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pneumatic");

// Populate 'Make' options for Air Pistols
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Artemis");
}
        });

        function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }

// Populate Model options based on selected Make
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", updateModels);
    document.getElementById("makeInput").addEventListener("change", updateModels);
    function updateModels() {
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    var make = document.getElementById("makeInput").value;
    var modelDropdown = document.getElementById("modelList");
    modelDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Model when Make changes


    if (type && make) { // Check if both type and make are selected
    switch (type) {
        case "Rifle":
            populateRifleModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
        case "Shotgun":
            populateShotgunModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
        case "Air Rifle":
            populateAirRifleModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
        case "Air Pistol":
            populateAirPistolModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
    }
}
}

        //Shotguns
        function populateShotgunModels(make, modelDropdown) {
        switch (make) {
    case "Abbiatico & Salvinelli":
        addOption(modelDropdown, "Dove");
    break;

case "Beretta":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "686");
            addOption(modelDropdown, "687");
break;
}
}

//Rifles
        function populateRifleModels(make, modelDropdown) {

    switch (make) {
         case "Accuracy International":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "AE");
break;
         case "Anschutz":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "1416");
break;
}
}

//Air Rifles

            function populateAirRifleModels(make, modelDropdown) {
// Populate Air Rifle model options based on the selected make
switch (make) {
        case "Air Arms":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "EV2 Mk1");
        break;
       }
     }

//Air Pistols
           function populateAirPistolModels(make, modelDropdown) {
           // Populate Air Pistol model options based on the selected make
switch (make) {
        case "Artemis":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "CP2");
        break;
      }
   }

function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }

// Populate Variant options based on selected Make + Model
    document.getElementById("makeInput").addEventListener("change", updateVariant);
    document.getElementById("modelInput").addEventListener("change", updateVariant);
    document.getElementById("variantInput").addEventListener("change", updateVariant);

    function updateVariant() {
    var make = document.getElementById("makeInput").value;
    var model = document.getElementById("modelInput").value;
    var variantDropdown = document.getElementById("variantList");
    variantDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Model when Make changes

    if (make && model) { // Check if both type and make are selected
    switch (make) {
        case "Accuracy International":
            populateAccuracyInternationalVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Artemis":
            populateArtemisVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Anschutz":
            populateAnschutzVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Beretta":
            populateBerettaVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Abbiatico & Salvinelli":
            populateAbbiaticoandSalvinelliVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Air Arms":
            populateAirArmsVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
     }
 }
}

//GUN VARIANTS BY BRAND A-Z//
        //"Accuracy International"
        function populateAccuracyInternationalVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "AE":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Black");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Blue");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Flat Dark Earth");
            break;
     }
}

            
               function populateAnschutzVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
               switch (model) {
                case "1416":
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Classic");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Classic Light");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "HB");
                break;
               }
            }

          
            function populateAirArmsVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
               switch (model) {
                case "EV2 Mk1":
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Grey");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Black");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Wood");
                break;
               }
            }

            function populateArtemisVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "CP2":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Red");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Blue");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Flat Dark Earth");
            break;
     }
}

function populateBerettaVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "686":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Long");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Short");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Double");
            break;
            case "682":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Long");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Short");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Double");
            break;
     }
}

function populateAbbiaticoandSalvinelliVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "Dove":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Red");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Blue");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Flat Dark Earth");
            break;
     }
}



function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }


// POPULATE STOCK MATERIAL BASED ON Type //
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", updateStock);
    document.getElementById("stockInput").addEventListener("change", updateStock);

    function updateStock() {
    var type = this.value;
    var stockDropdown = document.getElementById("stockList");
    stockDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Model when Make changes

if (type === "Rifle") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
if (type === "Shotgun") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
if (type === "Air Rifle") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
if (type === "Air Pistol") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
}

function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }


</script>

</body>
</html>



I believe event listeners may be suitable for this but I'm open to all HTML/Javascript suggestions. Many thanks for any help on how I can achieve this.

If I understood correctly, your question is just how to "open" a select using javascript code?

That is correct, but the opening needs to be triggered by selecting an option from the first list. Then once the second list opens and an option is selected in that list, the third list opens. And so on.

It doesn't change anything whether or not the Selects are cascaded or not, there is no way to "pre-open" a select from JS statements.

What you can do is set the .focus() of the following select element as soon as a choice in the current one has been made. This will at least direct the user's attention towards it.

As mentioned in my comment, you can switch the .focus() to the immediately following input element with
const inps=document.getElementById("upload-form").querySelectorAll("select","input");
["change"].forEach(etype=>inps.forEach((inp,i)=>inp.addEventListener(etype,gotoNext(i))));
function gotoNext(idx){
 return function(ev){
  if(idx<inps.length-1) inps[idx+1].focus();
}}

See below for a working snippet:


// Populate Action & Make options based on selected Product Type
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", function () {
        var type = this.value;
        var actionDropdown = document.getElementById("action");
        var makeDropdown = document.getElementById("makeList");
        var stockDropdown = document.getElementById("stockList");
        actionDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Action when Type changes
        makeDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Make when Type changes
        stockDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Stock when Type changes

// Populate 'Action' and 'Make' options for Rifles
        if (type === "Rifle") {
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Bolt Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Straight Pull");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Semi Automatic");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Single Shot");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pump Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Lever Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Over & Under");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Side-by-side");
        

             // Populate 'Make' options for Rifles
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Accuracy International");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Anschutz");
}

else if (type === "Shotgun") {
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Over & Under");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Side-by-side");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Semi Automatic");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Single Shot");

// Populate Make options for Shotguns
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Abbiatico & Salvinelli");
}

else if (type === "Air Rifle") {
            // Populate Action options for Air Rifles
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel - Spring");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel -Gas Ram");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pre-Charged Pneumatic (PCP)");

// Populate 'Make' options for Air Rifles
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Air Arms");
}

// Populate Action options for Air Pistols
        else if (type === "Air Pistol") {
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Select an Action");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel - Spring");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Break Barrel - Gas Ram");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pre-Charged Pneumatic (PCP)");
            addOption(actionDropdown, "Pneumatic");

// Populate 'Make' options for Air Pistols
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Select a Make");
            addOption(makeDropdown, "Artemis");
}
        });

        function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }

// Populate Model options based on selected Make
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", updateModels);
    document.getElementById("makeInput").addEventListener("change", updateModels);
    function updateModels() {
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
    var make = document.getElementById("makeInput").value;
    var modelDropdown = document.getElementById("modelList");
    modelDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Model when Make changes


    if (type && make) { // Check if both type and make are selected
    switch (type) {
        case "Rifle":
            populateRifleModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
        case "Shotgun":
            populateShotgunModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
        case "Air Rifle":
            populateAirRifleModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
        case "Air Pistol":
            populateAirPistolModels(make, modelDropdown);
            break;
    }
}
}

        //Shotguns
        function populateShotgunModels(make, modelDropdown) {
        switch (make) {
    case "Abbiatico & Salvinelli":
        addOption(modelDropdown, "Dove");
    break;

case "Beretta":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "686");
            addOption(modelDropdown, "687");
break;
}
}

//Rifles
        function populateRifleModels(make, modelDropdown) {

    switch (make) {
         case "Accuracy International":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "AE");
break;
         case "Anschutz":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "1416");
break;
}
}

//Air Rifles

            function populateAirRifleModels(make, modelDropdown) {
// Populate Air Rifle model options based on the selected make
switch (make) {
        case "Air Arms":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "EV2 Mk1");
        break;
       }
     }

//Air Pistols
           function populateAirPistolModels(make, modelDropdown) {
           // Populate Air Pistol model options based on the selected make
switch (make) {
        case "Artemis":
            addOption(modelDropdown, "CP2");
        break;
      }
   }

function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }

// Populate Variant options based on selected Make + Model
    document.getElementById("makeInput").addEventListener("change", updateVariant);
    document.getElementById("modelInput").addEventListener("change", updateVariant);
    document.getElementById("variantInput").addEventListener("change", updateVariant);

    function updateVariant() {
    var make = document.getElementById("makeInput").value;
    var model = document.getElementById("modelInput").value;
    var variantDropdown = document.getElementById("variantList");
    variantDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Model when Make changes

    if (make && model) { // Check if both type and make are selected
    switch (make) {
        case "Accuracy International":
            populateAccuracyInternationalVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Artemis":
            populateArtemisVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Anschutz":
            populateAnschutzVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Beretta":
            populateBerettaVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Abbiatico & Salvinelli":
            populateAbbiaticoandSalvinelliVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
        case "Air Arms":
            populateAirArmsVariants(model, variantDropdown);
        break;
     }
 }
}

//GUN VARIANTS BY BRAND A-Z//
        //"Accuracy International"
        function populateAccuracyInternationalVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "AE":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Black");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Blue");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Flat Dark Earth");
            break;
     }
}

            
               function populateAnschutzVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
               switch (model) {
                case "1416":
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Classic");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Classic Light");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "HB");
                break;
               }
            }

          
            function populateAirArmsVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
               switch (model) {
                case "EV2 Mk1":
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Grey");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Black");
                addOption(variantDropdown, "Wood");
                break;
               }
            }

            function populateArtemisVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "CP2":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Red");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Blue");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Flat Dark Earth");
            break;
     }
}

function populateBerettaVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "686":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Long");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Short");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Double");
            break;
            case "682":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Long");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Short");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Double");
            break;
     }
}

function populateAbbiaticoandSalvinelliVariants(model, variantDropdown) {
           switch (model) {
            case "Dove":
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Red");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Blue");
            addOption(variantDropdown, "Flat Dark Earth");
            break;
     }
}



function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }


// POPULATE STOCK MATERIAL BASED ON Type //
    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", updateStock);
    document.getElementById("stockInput").addEventListener("change", updateStock);

    function updateStock() {
    var type = this.value;
    var stockDropdown = document.getElementById("stockList");
    stockDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Refresh Model when Make changes

if (type === "Rifle") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
if (type === "Shotgun") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
if (type === "Air Rifle") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
if (type === "Air Pistol") {
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Black");
        addOption(stockDropdown, "Synthetic - Camo");
}
}

function addOption(selectElement, optionText) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = optionText;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
        }

const inps=document.getElementById("upload-form").querySelectorAll("select,input");
["change"].forEach(etype=>inps.forEach((inp,i)=>inp.addEventListener(etype,gotoNext(i))));
function gotoNext(idx){
 return function(ev){
  if(idx<inps.length-1) inps[idx+1].focus();
}}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Upload Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Product Upload Form</h2>
    <form id="upload-form" form action="Upload_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="type">Product Type:</label>
        <select id="type" name="type">
            <option value="">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="Shotgun">Shotgun</option>
            <option value="Rifle">Rifle</option>
            <option value="Air Rifle">Air Rifle</option>
            <option value="Air Pistol">Air Pistol</option>
        </select>

        <label for="action">Action:</label>
        <select id="action" name="action">
            <!-- Subcategory options will be dynamically added here -->
        </select>


    <div class="field-container">
        <label for="make">Make:</label>
        <input type="text" id="makeInput" name="make" list="makeList">
        <datalist id="makeList">
    <!-- Add options dynamically using JavaScript -->
        </datalist>



        <label for="model">Model:</label>
        <input type="text" id="modelInput" name="model" list="modelList">
        <datalist id="modelList">
        </datalist>


        <label for="variant">Variant:</label>
        <input type="text" id="variantInput" name="variant" list="variantList">
        <datalist id="variantList">
        <!-- Add options dynamically using JavaScript -->
        </datalist>


        <label id="stockLabel" for="stock">Stock Material:</label>
        <input type="text" id="stockInput" name="stock" list="stockList">
        <datalist id="stockList">
        </datalist>
    </div>
</form>



